# Computing difference in modular arithmetic.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Is there a meaningful kind of difference "$|a-b|$" in modular arithmetic?

For example, in mod $12$, we would like to have $|0-11|= 1$ and $|0-1| = 1$.

Comment: In modular arithmetic, there is no definition of positive vs negative elements, so how is $|x|$ to be defined?

Comment: my mistake. What I want to do is to compute the difference between two numbers in a given modulo system , so the difference between 11 and 12 is 1, in mod 12 and the difference between 12 and 1 is also 1 in mod 12. How would one accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases this is a wrong question to ask, because comparison is not a useful concept in modular arithmetic. Modulo $n$, all numbers are greater than 0 and all numbers are less than 0.

That said, if you *did* find a context in which the sort of function you are talking about was useful, I would say that all you would have to do is find the least non-negative value of $x$ such that $a-b-x$ is a multiple of the modulus, and the least non-negative value of $x$ such that $b-a-x$ is a multiple of the modulus (or $a-b+x$, it comes to the same thing). Then pick the smaller of the two numbers you have found.

Comment: Yes, and this is essentially the same as computing the distance between $a$ and $b$ in the ring consisting of $0$ to $n-1$ in order.